# Likelihood of vacuum decay event

Tags: vacuum

My understanding of the matter is currently limited to the wikipedia article about false vacuum.

One of my take aways of the article is, that we currently don‘t know if we live in an unstable, metastable or stable universe but that measuring the mass of the higgs bosom could tell us about the stability.

The current measuring inaccuracy allows for all three versions to be possible.

What I wonder is how this current ballpark in terms of stability (or decay likelihood) looks like. Let‘s say we live in the least stable universe that‘s possible given the current measuring inaccuracy, what would be the likelihood of a vacuum decay event, say within a one cubic light year over the course of 1 billion years?